# Dojo syntax for Eclipse Aptana plugin

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dojo, aptana

Using Aptana plugin for Eclipse version 3.7. Working on Dojo-powered project.

Aptana would mark every line that has Dojo tags (e.g. data-dojo-type) as incorrect syntax. What is the workaround to stop Eclipse from marking those tags as syntax errors?

Is there any way to at least add Dojo-tags as exceptions?

Comment: `data-` attributes are a valid part of HTML5.  While I can't speak to your specific IDE, I'd suggest looking around to make sure that it's treating your documents as HTML5 / is capable of properly validating HTML5.

Comment: Good point. Actually this solves the problem: In Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML Tidy Validator > Attributes >> Proprietary attributes --> ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid solution for the problem: In Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > HTML Tidy Validator > Attributes >> Proprietary attributes --> ignore